# In VB.Net, which file stream accept Seek end Peek methods?

Tags: vb.net, file, seek

I recently read on [Setting position index of filestream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12804488/setting-position-index-of-filestream-seek-to-retrieve-blocks-of-data-vb-net) that it is possible to use
`seek()` method of `BaseStream` class.

But now, using `.Net Framework 4.8` or greater these 2 functions seem to have been deleted.

Which stream in `.Net 4.8` or greater does implement this 2 functions ?

I search a solution that is distinct from [My.MyComputer.SystemFile.Seek()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.filesystem.seek?view=net-6.0) and is not restricted to using old VB 6 `FileOpen()` method !

Comment: Looks like it is still in 4.8. Are you sure? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.seek?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: That is what I explain in last line of my question. I refuse to use old VB6 technics. I search a pure VB.Net solution.

Comment: FileStream is part of System.IO and doesn't have anything to do with VB6 or FileOpen.

Comment: ok, FileStream is what I'm searching. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `System.IO.FileStream` class inherits the `System.IO.Stream` class. The latter provides the base functionality for all streams while the former provides functionality for streams backed by files. The `Seek` method is a member of the `Stream` class and thus every stream, regardless of type, has that method. That's true up to .NET 6 and will continue to be true as long as .NET exists.

The `Seek` method might throw a `NotSupportedException` in some cases, in which case the `CanSeek` property of that stream will be `False`. If you have a stream and you're not sure whether it can seek or not, test that property before calling `Seek` to ensure no exception will be thrown. In the case of a `FileStream`, the documentation (which you should already have read) tells us when to expect that property to be `False`:

> true if the stream supports seeking; false if the stream is closed or if the FileStream was constructed from an operating-system handle such as a pipe or output to the console.

You can read the documentation of other types of streams to see whether they support seeking, e.g. `MemoryStream` does and `NetworkStream` doesn't. Basically, seeking requires random access to all the data rather than just sequential access.

There is no `BaseStream` property on a `FileStream`. The property you refer to is a member of `StreamReader` class. That property will return a `Stream` reference to the stream being read. That could be a `FileStream`, `NetworkStream`, `MemoryStream` or whatever. If you have a `StreamReader` and you want to seek to a specific position in the underlying stream but you don't know whether it is supported or not then you get the `BaseStream`, test the `CanSeek` property and, if it's `True`, call the `Seek` method.

```vb
With myStreamReader.BaseStream
    If .CanSeek Then
        'Advance the file pointer 64 bytes.
        .Seek(64L, SeekOrigin.Current)
    End If
End With
```

That will work no matter what type of stream backs the reader because `CanSeek` and `Seek` are members of `Stream` and `StreamReader.BaseStream` is type `Stream`.

Comment: @schlebe, that is beyond the scope of this question. You should post a new question with ALL and ONLY the information relevant to the new issue. Note that `Position` will set the file pointer relative to the start of the file, so it is like using `Seek` with `SeekOrigin.Begin`, which is the most common. If you wanted to seek relative to the current position or the end, calling `Seek` is probably more natural.